# Netezza SQL query to concatenate the records of the specific column when the unique keys are same for more than one records

Tags: netezza

Concatenate multiple records for the specific column when the unique keys are same
Share the answer using subquery without inbuilt function

I have used groupconcat , listagg, stringagg non of them are accepting as a keyword in toad data point
Example
1 ram
1 ravi
2 raj
Output
1 ram, ravi
2 raj

Comment: Are you able to add examples of SQL you have tried so far?